# Adding sum of value back to Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary, and I'm trying to add 100 to the values. I'm able to do so, but I can't seem to figure out how to insert the new values to show up in the dictionary.

```
for value in artist_dict.values():
  value += 100
  
print(artist_dict)
```

I tried `.append(value)` and received an error message. Also, `value = artist_dict.values()`, `artist_dict.update(value)`, `artist_dict.values() = value`, and `artist_dict.updated(value +=100)` all received an error message.

Answer (score 0):

> *I'm trying to add 100 to the values.*
>
> ```py
> for value in artist_dict.values():
>   value += 100
> ```

When looping like this, `value` is just a **copy** of the respective item in `artist_dict.values()`, and has no effect on the actual `artist_dict` at all.

<sup>[For lists, you might use [`enumerate`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/enumerate) for something like this, but with a dictionary,]</sup> you can instead loop through the keys and access and increment the values via each key.

```py
for k in artist_dict:
    artist_dict[k] += 100
```

For more information see the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.clear) on `dict`; but basically,  *`for k in artist_dict`* does the same as `for k in artist_dict.keys()`, and the loop above effectively does the same as <kbd>`for k, v in artist_dict.items(): artist_dict[k] = v + 100`</kbd>.

---

---

> *...and received an error message.  Also, ...all received an error message.*

<sup>You should always include in your question what error messages you received, but in this particular case they're not hard to guess.</sup>

---

> I tried `.append(value)`

> `artist_dict.updated(value +=100)`

Dictionaries don't have those methods, so you can't apply them to `artist_dict`.

---

> `artist_dict.update(value)`

You need to send another dictionary as the argument in `.update`.

---

> `artist_dict.values() = value`

Afaik `.values()` can only be read, not set.